# How to distinguish between Mac OS Roman and UTF8

Tags: character-encoding

I have text file, how can I know the text in the file is in UTF8 standard or Mac OS Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file, the practical move is to open it e.g. in a web browser and test, via the browser’s View menu, how it looks like in the two encodings. If the encoding matters (i.e., there are characters outside the Ascii range 0–127), you should normally see the difference at once (at least if you can read the language of the document).

In programming, if you need to set up a general tool for resolving such questions automatically, it’s probably best to try to read the file (using your favorite programming language and tools) in the two encodings and check the success. If both ways give success, check out whether it can be read as Ascii too – if it can, the answer is trivial (the file is both UTF-8 and MacRoman encoded), and if not, you need some extra logic. In principle, inspection of the content is needed then, since the data can be interpreted both ways at the encoding level and only the content resolves which interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 files could start with a [byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) which would make them easy to recognize.

If they don't, you cannot know for sure but need to basically write the code to make an educated guess.

There are a couple of ways to make a guess;

- Scan the file for illegal UTF8-sequences, if they're there, the file should be MacRoman.
- Scan for "usual" characters in the files you're reading, if they're ascii 128 or higher, they'll be encoded differently in UTF-8 and MacRoman.

All characters <= ascii 127 should be identical between the two encodings, so if that's all there is in the files, the encoding doesn't matter, it will result in the same text.

Comment: There is no general recommendation that UTF-8 should start with BOM. It may, but the BOM is logically unnecessary in its basic function (since there is no byte order issue in UTF-8).

Comment: the text file I have is too large to go through, any suggestions?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Agreed, I reworded the answer so that it doesn't sound like it's a recommendation.

Comment: @sam You need to scan it somehow unless it has a BOM, that doesn't mean that you have to read it all at once into memory.